# How to implement MySQLi nested prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am trying to convert MySQL to MySQLi. And I cannot figure out why it brakes on

```
$stmt2->execute();
```

and returns error:

> `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Any issue or valid implementing of it!?

```
// SQL condition "WHERE group=''" where `group` is empty (NULL)
$result = "SELECT id, name FROM table WHERE group='' ORDER BY array ASC";

if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($result)) {
    $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);

    while ($stmt->fetch()) {
        // SQL condition "WHERE group='$id'" where $id defined in $stmt->bind_result($id, $name);
        $result2 = "SELECT name FROM table WHERE group='$id' ORDER BY array ASC";

        $stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($result2);
        //$valid_stmt2 = $stmt2 === FALSE ? false : true;

        echo $name . "\n";

        //if ($valid_stmt2) {
            // Error cased on $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->bind_result($name2);

            while ($stmt2->fetch()) {
                echo 'related to: ' . $name2 . "\n";
            }

            $stmt2->close();
        //}
    }

    $stmt->free_result();
    $stmt->close();
}
```

This question might be related to [Possible to use multiple/nested MySQLi statements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/112775/possible-to-use-multiple-nested-mysqli-statements) Unfortunately I did not find it helpful since it does not provide a valid example or resource for issue.

**Update: Simplified code example with comments.**

Comment: @hakre It is not an duplication of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999691/call-to-a-member-function-execute-on-a-non-object. I change `$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT url, name FROM links WHERE group='?' ORDER BY array ASC");` and added `$stmt2->bind_param("i", $id);`, but it still does not work. Anyone could provide a working example? The second `while ()` must return query results based on its condition - an `$id` from first `while ()`.

Comment: Ridiculous how community sees this question as exact duplicate to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8999691/call-to-a-member-function-execute-on-a-non-object. Requested re-check.

Answer (score 0):

You first did

```
"SELECT id, url, name FROM links WHERE group='' ORDER BY array ASC"
```

Then you want to use the `$id` to do

```
"SELECT url, name FROM links WHERE group='$id' ORDER BY array ASC"
```

How would get result for that? If group equal empty string, then it will not equal `$id`(only if `$id` is empty string too but that's non sense.)

Comment: `echo "$id <a href=$url>$name</a>";` will return `$id` value. What is wrong to return it in `"SELECT url, name FROM links WHERE group='$id' ORDER BY array ASC"`? Any issue?

Comment: @Binyamin Just your logic is wired, `group` won't be `''` and `'$id'` at same time.

Comment: @Binyamin And if your `'$id'` is not valid value will cause your sql to be wrong, please use placeholder instead.

Comment: If you fallow the code, the first query has condition where `group` is empty. The second query condition is `WHERE group='$id'` `$id` got from the first SQL query results. How you would return valid '$id'?