# (Nested MySQL statement) Is it possible to implement with one SQL query? Any improvements?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Is it possible to implement with one SQL query? Any improvements?

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT id, name FROM fruits WHERE `group`=''");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
        echo $row['name'];

        $query2   = mysql_query("SELECT name FROM fruits WHERE `group`='{$row['id']}'");

        if (mysql_num_rows($query2)) {
            echo ':';

            while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_array($query2, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
                echo ' '. $row2['name'] . ',';
            }
            mysql_free_result($query2);

            echo '<br>';
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
}
```

Result:

```
Berries: blueberry, raspberry, strawberry,
Citrus: grapefruit, lime,
Pear
```

Database structure `SELECT * FROM fruits`:

```
id   | group | name
-------------------------
03E7 |       | Berries
0618 | 03E7  | blueberry
051B | 03E7  | raspberry
02AA | 03E7  | strawberry
035F |       | Citrus
07A5 | 035F  | grapefruit
0633 | 035F  | lime
05E1 |       | Pear
```

Comment: Generally you'd do this with a self-join.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fully working example:

```
<?php

header("Content-Type: text/plain");

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("test");

$query = mysql_query("SELECT a.name as `group`, GROUP_CONCAT(b.name ORDER BY b.name SEPARATOR ', ') as name FROM fruits a LEFT JOIN fruits b ON b.`group` = a.id WHERE a.`group` = '' GROUP BY a.name");

if ($query) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        $group = $row['group'];
        $name  = $row['name'];

        if (isset($name)) {
            echo $group . ': ' . $name . "\n";
        } else  {
            echo $group . "\n";
        }
    }
    mysql_free_result($query);
}
mysql_close($con);

?>
```

Result:

```
Berries: blueberry, raspberry, strawberry
Citrus: grapefruit, lime
Pear
```

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT a.name as group_name, b.name as item_name
FROM fruits a
LEFT JOIN fruits b
ON b.`group` = a.id
WHERE a.`group` = ''
```

will get you a set of result rows that looks like...

```
group_name   item_name
----------------------
Berries      blueberry
Berries      raspberry
...          ...
Citrus       grapefruit
Citrus       lime
...          ...
Pear         NULL
```

You can then process this in your code to generate whatever final output you want.

Comment: So far with SQL, but how with PHP result?

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow isn't a site to just ask people to write all your code for you.

Comment: Here is what I tried http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043558/how-to-implement-mysqli-nested-prepared-statements#comment14451252_11043558, but it returned me a non-object error on second `prepare` statement.