# How to avoid repeated MySQLi connection for second `prepare` statement?

Tags: mysqli, prepared-statement

Why it stops to work on second `$mysqli->prepare($query)` statement?

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
...
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    // Code is working fine
    ...
    if ($stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($query2)) {
        // Code does not work
        ...
    }
}
```

And work fine with repeated `mysqli` connection:

```
$mysqli = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
$mysqli2 = @new mysqli(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE);
...
if ($stmt = $mysqli->prepare($query)) {
    // Code is working fine
    ...
    if ($stmt2 = $mysqli2->prepare($query2)) {
        // Code is working fine
        ...
    }
}
```

How to avoid repeated `mysqli` connection for second `prepare` statement?

---

**Update: As I see the community wants a real example:**

db table `fruits` with data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fruits` (
  `id` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `group` varchar(8) NOT NULL,
  `name` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

INSERT INTO `fruits` (`id`, `group`, `name`) VALUES
('03E7', '', 'Berries'),
('0618', '03E7', 'blueberry'),
('051B', '03E7', 'raspberry'),
('02AA', '03E7', 'strawberry'),
('035F', '', 'Citrus'),
('07A5', '035F', 'grapefruit'),
('0633', '035F', 'lime'),
('05E1', '', 'Pear');
```

php script:

```
<?php

$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test');
//$mysqli2 = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'password', 'test');

$query1 = "SELECT id, name FROM fruits WHERE `group`=''";
$query2 = "SELECT name FROM fruits WHERE `group`=?";

$stmt1 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt2 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
//$stmt2 = $mysqli2->stmt_init();

if($stmt1->prepare($query1)){
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($id, $name1);

    while($stmt1->fetch()){
        echo $name1;

        if($stmt2->prepare($query2)){
            $stmt2->bind_param('s', $group);
            $group = $id;
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->bind_result($name2);

            echo ':';

            while($stmt2->fetch()){
                echo ' ' . $name2 . ',';
            }
        }

        echo '<br>';
    }
}

?>
```

Result:

```
Berries
Citrus
Pear
```

Expected result:

```
Berries: blueberry, raspberry, strawberry,
Citrus: grapefruit, lime,
Pear:
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix the issue remove

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt2 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
```

and add after `$stmt1->execute();`

```
$stmt1->store_result();
```

and replace `$stmt1->prepare($query1)`, `$stmt2->prepare($query1)` with

```
$stmt1 = $mysqli->prepare($query1)
$stmt2 = $mysqli->prepare($query2)
```

Answer (score -1):

Does your code have the following?

```
$stmt = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt2 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
```

Then you can do:

```
if($stmt->prepare($query)) ...
if($stmt2->prepare($query2)) ...
```

Please post all of the code so I can see better what is going on.

**EDIT: OK, here is my worked example:**

Here is my table `links` with data:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `links` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `name` varchar(32),
  `group` varchar(32),
  `array` int(32),
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM;

INSERT INTO `links` (`id`, `name`, `group`, `array`) VALUES
(1, 'link1', '', 1),
(2, 'link1-sub-link1', '1', 1),
(3, 'link1-sub-link2', '1', 1),
(4, 'link2', '', 2),
(5, 'link3', '', 2),
(6, 'link3-sub-link1', '5', 2),
(7, 'link3-sub-link2', '5', 3),
(8, 'link3-sub-link3', '5', 3);
```

The following php code executes with no errors for me:

```
<?php
$mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "password", "things");

$query = "SELECT id, name FROM links WHERE `group`='' ORDER BY array ASC";
$query2 = "SELECT name FROM links WHERE `group`=? ORDER BY array ASC";

$stmt1 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
$stmt2 = $mysqli->stmt_init();
if($stmt1->prepare($query)){
    $stmt1->execute();
    $stmt1->bind_result($id, $name1);
    while($stmt->fetch()){
    echo $name1;
        if($stmt2->prepare($query2)){
            $stmt2->bind_param('s', $group);
            $group = $id;
            $stmt2->execute();
            $stmt2->bind_result($name2);
            while($stmt2->fetch()){
                echo 'related to: ' . $name2 . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion. It stops to work on second `prepare` statement `$stmt2->prepare($query2)`. Any other advice?

Comment: That's odd. Are you sure that $query2 is valid?

Comment: Both SQL queries are valid. The example with two MySQLi connections `$mysqli` and `$mysqli2` works fine. With one MySQLi connections `$mysqli` it stops on second `prepare` statement and probably has non-object issue, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11043558/how-to-implement-mysqli-nested-prepared-statements ?

Comment: I just fixed you PHP syntax. And it does not return the excepted result on latest PHP and MySQL. I have updated also my question with full code example so you can test it.